# Rails 3 update routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am having trouble with my routing in a Rails application.

My routing file has:

```
resources :translations
```

Which should create several routes, including update.

Doing a rake routes shows the update route is there:

```
PUT    /translations/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"translations"}
```

However, when I use the following code to link to the update:

```
<% form_tag( {:controller => "translations", :action => "update"}, {:multipart => true}) do %>
  <p><%= label_tag "upload", translate("UI_TEXT_FORM_SELECT_AUDIO_FILE") %>:
  <%= file_field_tag "upload" %></p>
  <%= submit_tag translate("UI_TEXT_FORM_SAVE") %>
<% end %>
```

I get this result:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/translations/10"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably looking for a route with POST. Try adding `:method => :put` in the options hash:

```
<% form_tag( {:controller => "translations", :action => "update"}, {:multipart => true, :method => :put}) do %>
```

Comment: Sure, no problem. Christian's advice is good, though: try to use `form_for` whenever possible. And it seems it will fit in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the :put method. For example:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "translations", :action => "update"}, :html => {:method => :put, :multipart => true}) do %>
```

Second, you should have an alias for the route. If its a RESTFUL route, which it looks like it is. You could do something like (below), instead of indicating which controller and action it should submit to.

```
<%= form_for(@transaction, :url => transaction_path, :html => {:method => :put, :multipart => true}) do %>
```

For your [reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).